# c# unsubscribe anonym method with extra parameters

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, events, anonymous-methods

I add images in `PictureBox` to a `TableLayoutPanel` and writing text on images with anonym methods, like this:

```
    private void AddPictureWithText(string text, int textX, int textY, int col, int row)
    {
        var picBox = new PictureBox()
        {
            Image = Properties.Resources.ProgressStage_LT_GRAY,
            SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.Zoom,
            Dock = DockStyle.Fill,
        };
        picBox.Paint += (sender, e) => { picPaint(sender, e, text, textX, textY); };
        tableLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(picBox, col, row);
    }

    private void picPaint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e, string text, int textPosX, int textPosY)
    {
        using (Font myFont = new Font("Arial", 12))
        {
            e.Graphics.DrawString(text, myFont, Brushes.White, new Point(textPosX, textPosY));
        }
    }
```

I need anonym method because I have to add extra parameters to `Paint event`.

**How can I  unsubscribe from this event?**

Comment: You have to save the delegate you are passing to the paint event for later using something like a private field. Then you can remove the delegate from some other point in your class.

Comment: Let the code speak. :)

Comment: `this.whatever = new Func<object, Eventargs>((sender, e) => { .... }); picBox.Paint += this.whatever;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You subscribed an anonymous method then to unsubscribe you need a reference to that method (which you have not). To make it more complicate it's also a closure then you can't simply move it to a plain class method.

First and most easy workaround (don't do it) is to store that delegate in the `Control.Tag` property. You can have a local variable or, in C# 7, a local function:

```
private void AddPictureWithText(string text, int textX, int textY, int col, int row)
{
    var picBox = new PictureBox
    {
        Image = Properties.Resources.ProgressStage_LT_GRAY,
        SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.Zoom,
        Dock = DockStyle.Fill,
        Tag = PaintPictureBox
    };

    picBox.Paint += PaintPictureBox;
    tableLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(picBox, col, row);

    void PaintPictureBox(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
        => picPaint(sender, e, text, textX, textY);
}
```

To remove it you just need to pick `PictureBox.Tag`, cast it to `PaintEventHandler` and remove it:

```
pbox.Paint -= (PaintEventHandler)pbox.Tag;
```

**Don't do it.** It's just a workaround for a wrong approach to the problem.

Let's do it in steps: first declare a *plain* `PaintEventHandler`:

```
private void PaintPictureBox(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
{
}
```

You then need some parameters, the best thing is probably to keep track of what you have to draw using a *model* but let's discuss about it later. For now you can add parameters you need to `Control.Tag`:

```
    var picBox = new PictureBox
    {
        Image = Properties.Resources.ProgressStage_LT_GRAY,
        SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.Zoom,
        Dock = DockStyle.Fill,
        Tag = new PaintModel { Text = text, Locaiton = new Point(textx, texty) }
    };
```

Inside `PaintPictureBox`:

```
var data = (PaintModel)((Control)sender).Tag;
```

And you can access `data.Text` and `data.Location`. Don't forget to declare the required `PaintModel` class/struct with the relevant properties (or to use named tuples). If you do not need any other property you may directly put the `Point` in the `Tag` property and use the *hidden* `PictureBox.Text` property for the title (in this case you, obviously, do not need `PaintModel` class/struct.)

**Don't do it**. This is just a slightly better approach because we're still messing with responsibilities (someone else is responsible to paint text in `PictureBox` instead of itself.) What's next? Let's introduce a custom control:

```
sealed class PictureBoxWithText : PictureBox
{
    public Point TextLocation { get; set; }

    public override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs pe)
    {
        base.OnPaint(pe);

        using (Font myFont = new Font("Arial", 12))
            pe.Graphics.DrawString(Text, myFont, Brushes.White, TextLocation);
    }
}
```

Your `AddPictureWithText()` will then be:

```
var picBox = new PictureBoxWithText
{
    Text = text,
    TextLocation = new Point(textx, texty),
    Image = Properties.Resources.ProgressStage_LT_GRAY,
    SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.Zoom,
    Dock = DockStyle.Fill,
};

tableLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(picBox, col, row);
```

**Slightly better**, we still have something to improve: we're creating (and correctly disposing) a `Font` object for each paint operation. It's slow and it consumes resources. Make it a private field:

```
sealed class PictureBoxWithText : PictureBox
{
    private readonly Font _textFont = new Font("Arial", 12);

    protected override Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        try
        {
            if (disposing)
                _textFont?.Dispose();
        }
        finally
        {
            base.Dispose(disposing);
        }            
    }

    // Existing implementation
}
```

If font is fixed then you may move it to a `static readonly` field (no need to overrride `Dispose(bool)` then).

Please remember that it's not the *perfect* or the *always-use-this* solution, if you're doing this to display a lot of pictures+text then adding 100+ controls will seriously hit performance, in that case you'd better keep a list of objects you're displaying and to perform paint accordingly (dropping the `TableLayoutPanel` and the `PictureBox` all together.)

Comment: I just needed 5 pictures, wont't be more.
Thanks. It solved my problem.
I used to derive the PictureBox class.